# BottomSheet : The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I've checked other posts having this problem and they said use `<merge>` instead of `<include>` but when i use `<merge>` it shows red in my `fragment.xml` file, there is no such tag. How can i solve this error?

In my `fragment.xml`:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/product_variation_bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my `Fragment.kt`:

```
var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet))
```

In my `bottom_sheet.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/productVariationBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0sp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    //some other views
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `<merge>` tags would go in the inner layout, not in place of the `<include>` tag. That's not your problem, though. The `<LinearLayout>` with the `BottomSheetBehavior` has ID `productVariationBottomSheet`, but you're looking for something else: `BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet))`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have parent layout as CoordinatorLayout. You put the CoordinatorLayout where you place the container. The container must be under the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Yes the Container is LinearLayout, then i included it with `<include>` in my fragment and the `<include>` tag is right under CoordinatorLayout. In activity, it works fine by just calling `findViewById()`, but if in fragment I have to use layoutInflater to get the layout, that's where the error happens

Comment: add CoordinatorLayout instead of LinnearLayout...if my answer is helpful please rate me

Comment: I tried moving LinearLayout one level lower, then make the root layout to CoordinatorLayout, and it shows BootomSheetBehaviour.from() requires LinearLayout. Then i put the bottom_sheet_behavior to the LinearLayout, one level below CoordinatorLayout, and other problems occured.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any solution to solve it, so i stopped using `<include>` and just put all the BottomSheet's layout code into my `fragment.xml` altogether. Then access the BottomSheet layout directly using `viewBinding`. This way, it works. Any other solution that works, feel free to share your solution.